# SharePoint (wss 3) and active directory username

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, wss-3.0

I am trying to find out where sharepoint gets the usernames from. In wss 3 on the "Personal settings" page there is a field name. In some cases it is populated with the login (like domain\username), on some installations I find it to be the actual name of the user. I guess that sharepoint at some point gets the real name from active directory - so that its not displayed "welcome domain\username", it should display "welcome firstname lastname" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Initially SharePoint uses the information from Active Directory to populate the fields in WSS. Next to that, there is a timerjob that runs to sync the information in AD and SharePoint, though I'm not sure whether this is MOSS feature only or that it's also available in WSS

Comment: Syncing the UserProfile properties from AD to SharePoint userprofile DB is MOSS only feature

Comment: Do you know which field in AD that sharepoint uses to populate the name property? In my case name gets the login id (domain\username) I am guessing that we are missing some information in AD.

Comment: but what about the initial property mapping? When a user is added for the first time, information is pulled fom AD to the user profile in sharepoint. Anyone has a mapping table for this? like what ad properties are added to which profile property in sharepoint?